# C++ OMP nested parallelisation not completely parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a program which unfortunately I need to abbreviate here since it is quite complex. The parallelisation is not working quite as expecting, on my 12 core laptop. I have 15 different kinds of calculations to run, on 20000-100000 points. For a given 'Call' if the number of points is fairly low (<10000), then paralellising those over 12 cores gives me no real gain in speed. So, I am trying to parallelise both the number of 'Calls' AND the number of points in a nested way, to get the best performance. At the same time, there is a limit to the number of point calculations I can pass to function3 due to memory issues.

In this case, nPoints is 23000, batch_size is 11500, n_threads_to_use is 2.
If I print omp_get_thread_num() inside function1, then I see 0-11 printed (but not 8, presumably used as a master thread). If I print omp_get_thread_num() inside function2, for each call is always printed 0 and 1.

Judging from the CPU usage, the program immediately ramps up towards using 1200% CPU (for the first 11 of the 15 Calls, but then for the remaining 4 calls, the CPU usage drops to 200%.

It seems the nesting is not working correctly.

1. How do the 0,1 thread_nums in function2 relate to the 0-11 threads reported in function1? Is it trying to run everything on the first 2 threads (surely not otherwise I wouldn't see 1200% CPU)
2. Should I set #pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS) to use 6 threads and not 12 if function2 will use 2 threads, or will this mean the entire parallel region is restricted to 6 (seems to me that it will limit to 6)?
3. Should I have a #pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS) inside function2 to use n_threads_to_use (ie. 2)?

I'm wondering if the #pragma critical section in function2 means that after doing the first 11, the remaining 4 are are executing one at a time due to waiting for some computation to finish, but I would have thought this section should be very quick.

I also read somewhere that omp_set_nested(1) is deprecated, so I don't know if OMP supports what I'm trying to do. Any help will be much appreciated.

The following is the abbreviated code:

```cpp
bool function1() {

  int N_THREADS = omp_get_max_threads();
  int nCalls = 15;

  int nPoints = 20000; // depends on the system, could be 100000

  XP = new float[nPoints];
  YP = new float[nPoints];
  ZP = new float[nPoints];

  for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) {
    XP[i] = getX(i); // pseudocode showing that XP[i] is assigned a coord value
    YP[i] = getY(i); // pseudocode showing that XP[i] is assigned a coord value
    ZP[i] = getZ(i); // pseudocode showing that XP[i] is assigned a coord value
  }

  int n_threads_to_use = (int)ceil(((float)nPoints / (float)MAX_BATCH_SIZE));
  int batch_size =
      (int)ceil(((float)nPts / (float)n_threads_to_use_per_probe) + 1);

  omp_set_dynamic(0);
  omp_set_nested(1);

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(N_THREADS)
  {
#pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < nCalls; i++) {
      function2(nPoints, n_threads_to_use, batch_size, XP, YP, ZP);
    }
  }
}

// n_threads_to_use is typically 1 or 2, batch_size is typically 20,000
// Function splits the number of points into batches for computation

bool function2(int nPoints, int n_threads_to_use, int batch_size, float *XP,
               float *YP, float *ZP) {

  float **XP_p, **YP_p, **ZP_p;

  XP_p = new float *[n_threads_to_use];
  YP_p = new float *[n_threads_to_use];
  ZP_p = new float *[n_threads_to_use];

  for (int i = 0; i < n_threads_to_use; i++) {
    XP_p[i] = new float[batch_size];
    YP_p[i] = new float[batch_size];
    ZP_p[i] = new float[batch_size];
  }

  int thread_n = 0;
  int batch_n = 0;
  int nPts = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++) {

    XP_p[thread_n][batch_n] = XP[i];
    YP_p[thread_n][batch_n] = YP[i];
    ZP_p[thread_n][batch_n] = ZP[i];

    nPtsBatch[thread_n]++;
    batch_n++;

    if (batch_n == batch_size) {
      batch_n = 0;
      thread_n++;
    }
  }

#pragma omp parallel
  {
#pragma omp for
    for (int ithread = 0; ithread < n_threads_to_use; ithread++) {
      function3(XP_p[ithread], XP_p[ithread], XP_p[ithread]);
    }
  }

#pragma omp critical
  {
    for (int ithread = 0; ithread < n_threads_to_use; ithread++) {
      collect_results_into_one_data_class();
    }
  }
}

bool function3(float *XP, float *YP, float *ZP) {
  // Run eg. specific calculations on the batches of points
}
```

Comment: hey, you'd be doing yourself a big favor if you ran this code through an automatic code formatter (such as your IDE/code editor surely provides!). systematically correct indentation makes code a lot easier to read, understand, talk about and see problems in. (done this for you, as I really had a problem seeing where loops and functions nest and how)

Comment: Thanks Marcus, and apologies - first time posting here and since my real code is a lot more complex I was just cutting/pasting lines and it seemed that there wasn't a good way to format in the site itself.

Comment: As an aside, I managed to get the program running almost twice as fast by moving most of the calculations that are in the #pragma critical section in collect_results_into_one_data_class() to be called after the #pragma critical section finishes. I guess if the threads are waiting here they are unavailable for the top level for loop which could be using them.

Comment: well, that's what a critical section does. Rule of thumb is that if your algorithm does any significant computation or worse more than the minimal necessary amount of collection as data movement in a critical section, well, it's not well parallelized. Generally, data exchange with your friendly neighborhood cores is significantly more expensive than computation, so that if there's not too much to be done in parallel, not using all cores is often faster.